# Which database table stores odoo user login details

Tags: odoo

Anyone know on which database table does odoo stores user login history?

We have a requirement to create a daily log history details of each user, I have searched res_users and other few tables, but haven't find any useful information about this.

Any hint will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this free module in Odoo app store. Think it will be helpful.
[User log details](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/login_user_detail/)

Comment: this doesn't fit our need.We need login and log out time of users,This app stores login time and IP address,So not fit for our requirement? ,but found this app which almost fit our need. https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/user_logs/  , but the thing is that user have to log out from the odoo for his to calculate the log out time, it cannot automatically logged out a session which is inactive for  a certain period and if the user didn't logged out it is not possible for this app to find the log out time.From the current database tables it is not possible?

Comment: I think it is not possible from the current database.
Take a look at the module https://apps.odoo.com/apps/modules/10.0/auth_session_timeout/ for session time out then log out.
I think you need  customization for your entire requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, really helped a lot :)